# The Period "." in Blender number pad emulate

Tags: interface

I emulated the number pad. But I do not know what key to use for the "." button.

Comment: Do you mean is there already a key mapped for "focus on selected" or are you looking for suggestions on which key to map?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure either, though I have a feeling not all keys on the numpad are emulated, just the numbers. If you filter the key map by KeyBinding/numpad then you can assign whichever functions you like (in this case probably 3D View / View Selected) to alternative keys.

Comment: what do we do for the numpad .? whats the setting called

Answer (score 0):

On version 2.83.5: ALT + MIDDLEMOUSE will center the view of the clicked object. Then you have to use mousewheel to zoom.

Comment: what about for 2.79